How to find out the user's preferences for the preferred scrolling direction of the touchpad
Is there any way to find out the user's preferences for the preferred scrolling direction of the touchpad? Does the user prefer natural/inverted scrolling direction or standard?

I don't think there's a common (and multi platform) way to retrieve the OS or user configuration. You normally assume that based on the inverted() property of the wheel event. You can eventually check the event source with deviceType().

@musicamante I need to retrieve this information outside the wheel event handler.
